# Como Tratar variável preenchida por NAN Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `<input/>` em HTML que ao ser preenchido disparada alguns cálculos para preencher automaticamente os demais *inputs*, mas caso eu não preencha o dado este `<input/>` que dispara a função de Javascript o valor do seguinte `<input/>` que vai o resultado fica com `NAN` tem como eu tratar isto e deixar o `<input/>` zerado caso ocorra isso?

**Função Javascript**

```
function calcValor(){
    var PRECO = 0;
    var PORCENTAGEM = 0;
    var ENTRADA = 0;
    var QT = 0;
    var VDESCONTO = 0;
    var TOTAL = 0;
    // zerando total
    document.getElementById("total").value = '0';
    // Preço do produto
    PRECO = parseInt(document.getElementById("valorProduto1").value);

    // Porcentagem do desconto
    PORCENTAGEM = parseInt(document.getElementById("desconto").value);

    ENTRADA = parseInt(document.getElementById("entrada").value);

    QT = document.getElementById("qtProduto1").value;

    if ()
    VDESCONTO = parseInt(PRECO*(PORCENTAGEM/100));

    Total = parseInt(PRECO)*QT - (parseInt(ENTRADA + VDESCONTO));

    document.getElementById("vdesconto").value = VDESCONTO.toFixed(2); 
    document.getElementById("sp_vdesconto").innerText = VDESCONTO.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").value = TOTAL.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("sp_total").innerText = TOTAL.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("debito").innerText = DEBITO.toFixed(2);
} 

function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}

function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function float(v){
    v=v.replace(",",".")
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para detectar a ocorrência de um `NaN` (Not a number) você deve usar a função [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) passando o valor.

```
var nan = 0 / 0;
var eNaN = Number.isNaN(nan); // eNaN vai ser true, pois zero sobre zero não é um número
```

No seu exemplo a fonte do NaN é o `parseInt` que retorna NaN para qualquer coisa que não possa ser reconhecido como número:

```
var numero = parseInt("xpto");
if (Number.isNaN(numero))
    numero = 0; // zerando caso seja NaN
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! resolvi desta forma:

  if(Number.isNaN(TOTAL))
    TOTAL = 0;